# Open PowerShell from Run Window

Tags: windows-7, powershell-3.0

I was looking for a command to fire up PowerShell from the Run window.
I type in '`powershell`' in run window.
And it does fire up Windows PowerShell - but why it looks like 'Command Prompt' window(Black background).
Why I am missing that blue screen that comes when I open PowerShell from Accesssories->Windows PS?

Any ideas?

Comment: For future reference, questions like this would be better served at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for PowerShell ISE, not PowerShell.

Powershell:

[image: Powershell screen image]

Powershell ISE:

[image: Powershell ISE screen image]

Instead of typing `PowerShell` into the run window, type `PowerShell_ISE`.

Comment: Not correct. The question is asking how to get the look n feel for PS window when started from command prompt so that it looks similar to when manually run from start program. It has nothing to do with ISE which is authoring environment.

Comment: Yup i read it. When u run PowerShell from Accessories -> Windows PS you get PowerShell you get PowerShell in its Blue avatar. But when u run it from cmd.exe, you get black avatar like cmd prompt. It was corrected in win 10 later server os. Nothing to do with ISE. ISE is not same as PowerShell.exe. Many features like Transcript doesnt work in ISE.

Comment: @AmanSharma: I guess if the user ever comes back (it's been two years since the question was asked) we'll know for sure what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

The blue screen you are used to seeing is configured in the shortcut, not in the PowerShell executable. By starting PowerShell from the Run dialog box instead of the shortcut, you are not going to see the shell configuration options that are defined in the shortcut.

One way to control how your PowerShell window appears is to setup your profile to set the values you want. You can control the foreground (text) and background colors, font style and size, window position and size, etc. The Microsoft manual covering the profile is located [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692764.aspx).

This will make your window appear the same way whether you use a shortcut or the Run dialog. FYI... you can still start a session without the profile if you decide you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can set window properties in your profile. There is possible to set background color, font color, buffer,window size, ...
Check if you already have profile file:

```
Test-Path $profile
```

If not create it:

```
New-Item -path $profile -type file -force
```

Now you can edit profile:

```
notepad $profile
```

Example of profile settings:

```
$Shell = $Host.UI.RawUI
$size = $Shell.BufferSize
$size.width=120
$size.height=3000
$Shell.BufferSize = $size
$size = $Shell.WindowSize
$size.width=120
$size.height=50
$Shell.WindowSize = $size
$shell.BackgroundColor = “Magenta”
$shell.ForegroundColor = “White”
cls
```

As you can see it is normal powershell script so you can set other properties and execute other commands.

Answer (score 0):

Typing in PowerShell from the Windows command line will execute PowerShell, however it will keep the same style, i.e., black background.

If you search for PowerShell in your Start Menu it will pull all actual programs available, PowerShell and PowerShell ISE (blue backgrounds).